# inserting json into cassandra table using spark streaming

Tags: cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark streaming to pull some data from kafka to store in cassandra. The data coming from kafka is in json format and looks like this

> {"message":"testing from kafka appender with
>   exception","loggerName":"com...KafkaAppenderTest","params":null,"complete":"fake
>   exception"}

Here is my code to create a stream from kafka messages

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, String.class, String.class,
            StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topicsSet);
```

map the stream to pull out the json message and parse to form a `LogEvent` object

```
messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, LogEvent>() {
        @Override
        public LogEvent call(Tuple2<String, String> v1) throws Exception {
            Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(v1._2, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });
            return new LogEvent(map);
        }
    })
```

finally, write each rdd to cassandra

```
.foreach(new Function2<JavaRDD<LogEvent>, Time, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call(JavaRDD<LogEvent> rdd, Time v2) throws Exception {
            javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("myks", "logs", mapToRow(LogEvent.class)).saveToCassandra();
            return null;
        }
    })
```

This works fine but I would like to not have to convert the json string to `LogEvent` object, instead, I want to just pass the json string to cassandra and utilize its json parsing functionality to insert data into the table directly from the json. This way, I dont have to know what is coming in the json and as long as the column names match, the data will/should get mapped to the table. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this ?